# How to move an eDirectory entry via php?

Tags: php, ldap, edirectory

I have this ldap entry:

`cn=blah,ou=apples,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu`

I need to move that entry to:

`cn=blah,ou=oranges,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu`

My scripts are all PHP so I've been trying to use php.net/ldap_rename

```
ldap_rename($connection, "cn=blah,ou=apples,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu", "cn=blah", "ou=oranges,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu", true);
```

Does not work. It returns false.

This https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-rename.php#82393 comment mentions that eDirectory wants to leave the parent as NULL. Like:

```
ldap_rename($connection, "cn=blah,ou=apples,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu", "cn=blah", NULL, true);
```

That returns TRUE but does not actually move the entry. Not surprising since it's not changing the parent... I'm sure it could change the cn=blah to something else...

I have thought of deleting the entry and recreating it. But that's a painful way to go about it. Writing out and running a LDIF file would also be painful.

So, how do I move an entry from one OU to another, in php, without the pain of my other two options?

What I'm running:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- PHP 5.3.10
- eDirectory 8.8 is on SLES 11

### Edit

So, I found this:

> The modrdn change type cannot move an entry to a completely different subtree. To move an entry to a completely different branch, you must create a new entry in the alternative subtree using the old entry's attributes, and then delete the old entry.

From http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Creating_Directory_Entries-LDIF_Update_Statements.html

I found a couple other pages with similar statements.

So it sounds like I have to make a new entry, copying the attributes, the delete the old one. Like the second painful option I mentioned above.

Comment: could you advise as to the version of LDAP you're running?

Comment: The stated comment talks explicitly about renaming and not moving an entry. So it does not apply here. Did you try to give it a complete dn though in the third parameter? And are you sure that the user binding to the LDAP has sufficient rights?

Comment: LDAP v3. Earlier in the code I set the protocol explicitly. The user I'm testing with is the main admin to the directory. So it has the right perms.

Comment: Just tried passing the full new dn to the third parameter. ldap_rename returned true, but eDirectory did not move the entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I ended up using the "create new entry, delete old one" method. I still think I had another way working a while back, but I can't remember what. So here's a basic move function.

```
function move($connection, $ldapEntryReference, $new_dn){        
    //First, get the values of the current attributes.
    $attributes = array(); //start attributes array
    $firstattr = ldap_first_attribute($connection, $ldapEntryReference);
    $value = ldap_get_values($connection, $ldapEntryReference, $firstattr);
    $attributes[$firstattr] = $value;
    while($attr = ldap_next_attribute($connection, $ldapEntryReference)) {
        if (strcasecmp($attr, 'ACL') !== 0) { //We don't want ACL attributes since 
                                              //eDir/ldap should deal with them for us.
            if (strcasecmp($attr, 'jpegPhoto') === 0) {
                //binary values need to use the ldap_get_values_len function.
                $value = ldap_get_values_len($this->connection, $ldapEntryReference, $attr);
            } else {
                $value = ldap_get_values($this->connection, $ldapEntryReference, $attr);
            }
            $attributes[$attr] = $value;
        }
    }
    //Create a new entry array with the values.
    $entry = array(); //start entry array.
    foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            if (strcasecmp($key2, 'count') !== 0) {//get rid of 'count' indexes
                                                   //ldap_add chokes on them.
                $entry[$key][$key2] = $value2;
            }
        }
    }
    //Add the new entry.
    if (ldap_add($connection, $new_dn, $entry)) {
        //Delete the old entry.
        if (ldap_delete($connection, ldap_get_dn($connection, $ldapEntryReference)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone, sometime.

Comment: Please note that the 5th to last line of the function is missing a closing parenthesis. It should be    if (ldap_delete($connection, ldap_get_dn($connection, $ldapEntryReference))) {

Answer (score 0):

There actually isn't a need to recreate in eDir. Doing a recreate causes problems in an environment that runs IDM as the object will have a new GUID and the IDM engine will not see the event as a true "move".

The following code moves users fine (tested eDir 8.8.x & eDir 9.x):

```
$olduserdn = "cn=userid,ou=container1,o=org";
$newdestdn = "ou=container2,o=org";
if (preg_match('/^(cn=[A-Za-z0-9]+)\,(.+)/i', $olduserdn, $rdnmatches))
{
    if (ldap_rename($ldapconn, $olduserdn, $rdnmatches[1], $newdestdn, TRUE))
    {
        print("Moved $olduserdn to $rdnmatches[1],$newdestdn");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Failed move because " . ldap_error($ldapconn));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to give a bit of time for replication...

Also consider constraints around modifying/moving objects that are still being replicated from a previous move event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ldap_rename($ldapconn, "cn=blah,ou=apples,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu", "cn=blah", "ou=oranges,ou=people,dc=yay,dc=edu", true);
```